# have multiple input pywebio

Tags: python, web-applications, python-webbrowser

I want to build a web app by pywebio to ask the configurations of a device to find the best fit for its data. In this application we have to choose which algorithms we want to use to find the best fit. I want to be able to input configurations and have a button to add as many as new fit type in the same page.
For having multiple input I used input_groups() but I dont know how can I add dynamic new input fields in it. I tried to use the "to-do list" official demo but it only has one input I want to have all input and a dynamic input in the same page.
I hope I'm clear, In the photo [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdj8d.png) I want to have something like the red part that I can add as many fit type as I want without going to a new page, when I push on Add button a slide input should appear that I can choose from options.
please just tell me how should I define the new input without re writing all the page.

my code is:

```
data = input_group("input info",[
select("please select DeviceEUI:", options=deviceeuis, name='DeviceEUI',
       onchange=lambda c: euichange(c)),
select("please select Device name:", options=devicenames, name='device_name',
       onchange=lambda c: namechange(c)),
select('base_gasID',  options= ['Select Base gas'],name='base_gasID', type=TEXT),
input('file_name', name='file_name', type=TEXT),
input('date_start', name='date_start', type=DATE),
input('time_start', name='time_start', type=TIME),
input('date_end', name='date_end', type=DATE),
input('time_end', name='time_end', type=TIME),
```

Comment: what demo do you means ?I don't see any `to-do list` demo in documentation. You could add link in question (not in comment). If `to-do list` shows how to add dynamic field then rather shouldn't be problem to do it with many fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use scopes to wrap each input fields, and show or hide them according different input configurations.
Get details at https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/v1.6.1/output.html#pywebio.output.use_scope